# pandas qcut with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign the elements of the rows of a dataframe into quartiles. The rows however could have NaNs only, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan, 20, 30, 40],
                   'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 31, 41],
                   'C': [np.nan, 22, 32, 42],
                   'D': [np.nan, 23, 33, 43],
                   'E': [np.nan, np.nan, 34, np.nan]
                  }
)
```

I am trying to bucket the dataframe with qcut but I am hitting an error because of the top row (I think). When I run

```
df.T.apply(lambda x: x.where(not (x.isna().all()), pd.qcut(x, 4, labels=False)).T)
```

it drops me

```
IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Ideally, I want to keep the `NaNs` at the top row and apply the `qcut` function on the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
(df.T.apply(
    lambda x: x.dropna().pipe(pd.qcut, 4, labels=False) 
    if not x.isna().all() else x).T)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D    E
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  0.0  NaN  1.0  3.0  NaN
2  0.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
3  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
```